# Bash history for remote hosts

Tags: bash, ssh, command-history

I want to have the benefits of bash history command lookup, but working on multiple hosts I ssh to. However, I don't have a home directory on most of the remotes due to security policy, so there is no `~/.bash_history` there. `export HISTFILE=/tmp/blah` does not work for current session. Even if I had a file there, it should be sync'ed across multiple remotes through some local file.

A solution should probably look like this:

Through `.ssh/config` or `alias` or somehow, execute something around every ssh command, e.g.

```
scp .remote-history user@remote:/tmp/history
ssh user@remote
scp user@remote:/tmp/history .remote-history.add
cat .remote-history.add >> .remote-history
```

unless there is an existing tool that does something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This script (remote_run) should do what you want.  it could be made much prettier, but...

https://gist.github.com/wwalker/c2677ec6dfef31cdaecad855e3f4df60

Run it like:

remote_run remote_hostname

When you exit, it will overwrite (so don't have two concurrent remote_runs to th same host or the last one win for whose history is saved) your local file ~/.bash_history-remote_hostname

```
#!/bin/bash
# version 0.0.1

LOCALHISTFILE=/tmp/$USER.history.$$;
read -d '' RUN << EOF
export HISTFILE=$LOCALHISTFILE;
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T - '
bash -i;
awk '{print \"HIST \"\$0}' \$HISTFILE;
EOF
ssh $1 "cat > $LOCALHISTFILE" < ~/.bash_history-$1
ssh -t $1 "$RUN" | tee /tmp/$USER-remote-history
grep '^HIST ' /tmp/$USER-remote-history | sed -e 's/^HIST //' -e 's/^M//' > ~/.bash_history-$1
```